# How to get a list of files in the bundle in webpack after treeshake

Tags: javascript, webpack, conditional-compilation, webpack-plugin

I am trying to get a list of files that end up in my build after treeshaking. I use conditional compilation constants to remove dev/debug code from bundle and Webpack is doing a good job with treeshaking, I don't find any dev code in the resulted build. But I want to write some code that would check wether some dev files ended up in production build by mistake.

I've tried `NormalModuleReplacementPlugin` but Webpack still load imports even if they are not used, it has to analyse all the sources to determine whether any of them are a dead code.

I've tried adding plugin to `emit` stage hook and going through all the modules and checking resources, but I still find references to my dev code file there, even though they don't end up in the resulted build.

```
class DevImportsMonitorPlugin {
    apply(compiler) {
        compiler.hooks.emit.tapAsync('DevImportsMonitor', (compilation, callback) => {
            compilation.chunks.forEach(chunk => {
                // explore chunk
                chunk.getModules().forEach(module => {
                    // explore modules
                })
            });
            callback();
        });
    }
}
```

I've put a breakpoint there and explored the context of chunks and modules, but it still has references to the dev/test modules.

Maybe there is a way to determine maybe what module was removed from the output?

Comment: The Terser Plugin removes the unused code.

Comment: Is there a way to get removed code references, or what actually ended up in the build?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this yesterday it's pretty cool; https://www.excitoninteractive.com/articles/read/65/webpack4/step-by-step-bundle-analyzer-plugin

Comment: My goal is to detect presence of a source file in the build programatically and fail the build if so. I can ofc analyze and check it manually, but BundleAnalyzer is not very useful here since my source code ends up being reported as "Main.ts + 134 concatenated modules".

Comment: yes, be aware that the bundle-analyizer cannot show the treeshaked modules (because terser does this)